# Generate a specific array in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to easily generate this array in Ruby?

```
[[-5,'-5'],[-4,'-4'],[-3,'-3'],[-2,'-2'],[-1,'-1'],[1,'1'],[2,'2'],[3,'3'],[4,'4'],[5,'5']]
```

Basically, it contains 10 elements from -5 to 5 with an integer key and string value.

Comment: What do you mean by simplify? Maybe it would be better if you showed how you were using the array.

Comment: Generate the array with call instead of declare each value.

Comment: Why do you want that array? It doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: To create a dropdown with those options using `best_in_place` gem. The integer value is what will be saved on the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(-5..5).map{ |i| [i, i.to_s] }
```

doester pointed out that the spec does not include `0`, any of these would work:

```
(-5..5).reject{ |i| i == 0 }.map{ |i| [i, i.to_s] }
(-5..5).reject(&:zero?).map{ |i| [i, i.to_s] }
(-5..5).map{ |i| [i, i.to_s] unless i == 0 }.compact
(-5..5).ma­p{ |i| [i, i.to_­s] unles­s i.zer­o? }.com­pact
```

Comment: Either this answer, or the specification is wrong. The spec does not include an [0, "0"] element.

Comment: My favorite is the one with `reject(&:zero?)`

Answer (score 1):

`((-5..-1).to_a + (1..5).to_a).map { |i| [i, i.to_s] }`